# OpenCV CvConvexityDefects can't work and can't detect fingers！

Tags: opencv, convex-hull

I'm using OpenCv to detect fingertips, but now I meet with some obstacles!
The findContours & convexHull & convexityDefects method doesn't work with my project.
It's my first time to ask a question. Thanks everybody!

My code is below:

```
int main()
{
CvScalar white = cvRealScalar(255);
CvScalar black = cvRealScalar(0);

CvSeq* contours = 0;
CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("h.jpg");
IplImage* imgGray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), img->depth, 1);
IplImage* contoursImg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), img->depth, 1);
cvZero(contoursImg);
int nWidth = contoursImg->width;
int nHeight = contoursImg->height;
int nChannels = contoursImg->nChannels;
int nStep = contoursImg->widthStep;
for (int i=0; i<nHeight; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<nWidth; j++)
        contoursImg->imageData[i*nStep + j*nChannels] = 255 - contoursImg->imageData[i*nStep + j*nChannels];

cvCvtColor(img, imgGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cvThreshold(imgGray, imgGray, 230, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
cvSmooth(imgGray, imgGray);

cvFindContours(imgGray, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));
contours = cvApproxPoly(contours, sizeof(CvContour), storage, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, 35, 1);
cvDrawContours(contoursImg, contours, CV_RGB(0, 0, 0), CV_RGB(0, 0, 0), 1, 1, 8, cvPoint(0, 0));

CvSeq* hull = cvConvexHull2(contours, 0, CV_CLOCKWISE, 0);
CvSeq* defect = cvConvexityDefects(contours, hull, NULL);
for(; defect; defect = defect->h_next)
{
    int nomdef = defect->total;
    if(!nomdef)
        continue;
    CvConvexityDefect* defectArray = (CvConvexityDefect*)malloc(sizeof(CvConvexityDefect)*nomdef);
    cvCvtSeqToArray(defect, defectArray, CV_WHOLE_SEQ);
    for(int i = 0; i < nomdef; i++)
    {
        cvCircle(contoursImg, *(defectArray[i].end), 5, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), -1, 8, 0);
        cvCircle(contoursImg, *(defectArray[i].start), 5, CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), -1, 8, 0);
        cvCircle(contoursImg, *(defectArray[i].depth_point), 5, CV_RGB(0, 0, 255), -1, 8, 0);
    }
    free(defectArray);
}

cvNamedWindow("image", 1);
cvShowImage("image", contoursImg);

cvWaitKey(0);
cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);
cvReleaseImage(&img);
cvReleaseImage(&imgGray);
cvReleaseImage(&contoursImg);
cvDestroyWindow("image");

return 0;       
}
```

This is my hand picture:

http://www.billwang.net/bbs/oldattach/2006/12/29/billwang_5315954-038-embed.jpg

Comment: Your code works like a charm for your image. I am able to generate the contour image. What error are you getting?

Comment: Thank you, go4sri. The code can generate the contour image. But it should also generate small black circles on the fingertips; unfortnately, the result isn't what I want.

Comment: cvConvexHull2 funciton and cvConvexityDefects function and the following "for" loop should detect and mark the fingertips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods are working fine. You have one rectangular contour detected on the outside of the image. As this covers the entire image, there are no defects and so, none detected. See attached image.[image: Look at the cyan box on the outside of the image]

Comment: Well, I also found the contour covering the entire image this morning (in China). And I added some codes to clear the outside contour and only keep the contour of hand before using the convexHull & convexityDefects fncitons. I'm sorry that I am not able to vote up your answer because my rep core is only one. Thank you very much, @go4sri!

Comment: very good answer...I voted up for this fellow's answer...would be very helpful if you can share some more knowledge about this function in openCV here in this thread itself.